# Does MongoDB support logical operator in the updating expression?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

For example, my code is below

```
b = c.test.users.find_one_and_update(
      {'uid': u'52ae5c7a48bd9ffb716bf4f774954d20'}, 
      {'$set': {'user_id': '111'}, 
       '$and': [{'device_id': {'$ne': u'c09b46863f953bec1d5c0a1a'}},
                {'$set': {'device_id': 'abc'}}]}
```

and I get a exception `OperationFailure: Unknown modifier: $and`. It seems the MongoDB does not support logical operator like `$and` in the updating expression. Does it?

---

UPDATED(Answer @chridam):

The above code is just a example which want to show a situation: to find a user document with a specified `uid`, set it's `user_id`, and set the `device_id` only when the `device_id` is not equal to some value, such as a historian value.

Comment: Only the delegated [**update operators**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1) can be used, anything else MongoDB will complain and throw an error. Why can't you just run this as an atomic update `{ 'uid': u'52ae5c7a48bd9ffb716bf4f774954d20', 'device_id': { '$ne': u'c09b46863f953bec1d5c0a1a' } }, { '$set': { 'user_id': '111', 'device_id': 'abc' } }`, why include logical operators where they shouldn't be?

Comment: can you write your document schema and expected result?

Comment: @chridam I've updated my question to clean my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First pass the condition then update result. You can't pass two separate conditions like you have done. Try below:

```
    c.test.users.find_one_and_update(
          {'uid': u'52ae5c7a48bd9ffb716bf4f774954d20'}}, 
          {'$set': {'user_id': '111', 'device_id': 'abc'}}, {new: true}, function(err, user){
  if(err) return next(err);
if(user.device_id !== 'c09b46863f953bec1d5c0a1a'){
   user.device_id = 'abc';
user.save();
}
})
```

**UPDATE:**

```
db.example.find_one_and_update(
     {'uid': u'52ae5c7a48bd9ffb716bf4f774954d20'}},
     {'$set': {'user_id': '111', 'device_id': 'abc'}},
     return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

after getting this result you can change in returned object and then save it.

P.S.: As save() is deprecated in 3.0 so if you are using >3.0 version then use replace_one();

**< 3.0**

```
   var newUser = db.example.find_one_and_update(
         {'uid': u'52ae5c7a48bd9ffb716bf4f774954d20'}},
         {'$set': {'user_id': '111', 'device_id': 'abc'}},
         return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER);

if(newUser.device_id !== 'c09b46863f953bec1d5c0a1a'){
   newUser.device_id = 'abc';
db.example.save(newUser);
}
```

**>=3.0**

```
  var newUser = db.example.find_one_and_update(
         {'uid': u'52ae5c7a48bd9ffb716bf4f774954d20'},
         {'$set': {'user_id': '111', 'device_id': 'abc'}},
         return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER);

    if(newUser.device_id !== 'c09b46863f953bec1d5c0a1a'){
    db.example.replace_one({'uid': u'52ae5c7a48bd9ffb716bf4f774954d20'}, {'device_id': 'abc'})
}
```

Comment: Your answer have changed my problem. Please read my updation in the question(I've just updated). Thank you.

Comment: I find the prototype of `find_one_and_update` is `find_one_and_update(filter, update, projection=None, sort=None, return_document=ReturnDocument.BEFORE, **kwargs)`. Does you mean `find_one_and_update(..., ..., projection={new: true}, sort=function(err, user) {...})`?

Comment: I refer to this [official reference manual](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update) of `find_one_and_update`.